# Image link not showing image

Tags: java, html, vaadin

I am using Java and Vaadin to create a simple view where an image is displayed. I have a single Image element containing a source link. Here is my code.

```
@Route(value = "")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

  public MainView() {
    add(new Image("https://media.reaperscans.com/file/4SRBHm/comics/14659ab2-5650-4aaf-a5bb-9ad5a9828662/chapters/3aff6399-5ff4-46d1-b502-88788510d962/000.jpg", ""));
  }
}
```

This compiles to a HTML in the browser containing an image element:

```
<img src="https://media.reaperscans.com/file/4SRBHm/comics/14659ab2-5650-4aaf-a5bb-9ad5a9828662/chapters/3aff6399-5ff4-46d1-b502-88788510d962/000.jpg">
```

When I open this image in new tab I can see the image correctly, but when I see it in my app there is only:
[image]

EDIT:

I can open the image using the link in Google Chrome.
[image]

Comment: Usually this means, that you are not allowed to embed the image in your website. Are some messages in the browser console?

Comment: Now that I look there I can see: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`. Is there no way to override this on localhost?

Comment: That sounds like the server doesn't you to link to that image directly from your page.

Comment: I believe it should be possible to show the image if I set the user agent parameter to the header of the request, I just have not found out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the image on Chrome you will notice the website doesn't allow hotlinking. That's why it doesn't load. Try using a different image (from Wikipedia, for example) and it should work well.

[image: Hotlinking not allowed]

```
new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Vaadin-flow-bakery.png","vaadin");
```

I recommend using the alt attribute as well, instead of leaving it empty as you had in your original question.

Comment: I just edited the question with a screenshot allowing me to view the image as is in Google Chrome. Is there any way to get around the website disabling hotlinking?

Comment: There is a reason why they don't allow hotlinking. Even when you find a technical workarround, legaly this is not a safe thing to do.